# Issue with environment variable in batch script

Tags: batch-file

So, I have probably a simple question but I cannot seem to find an easy answer.

Issue: I have a file that contains a set of lines such as:

```
%windir%\file.exe  
%windir%\file2.dll
```

and so forth...

What I am trying to do is echo the actual file path to a second file such that the resulting output would be something like:

```
C:\Windows\file.exe  
C:\Windows\file2.dll
```

and so forth...

The actual source file could have other variables such as `%programfiles%` but all of them have a resulting actual path.

I am currently using a `for /f loop` but when I echo the variable, I just get the environment variable returned rather than the actual path to the file.

Is there a solution out there for batch scripting?

---

The actual script is below.  Note I am all for making this more efficient as time to get the information is important.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services" >> registry_hklm_installed_services_tmp.txt 2>nul

reg.exe query "HKLM\System\ControlSet001\Services" >> registry_hklm_installed_services_tmp.txt 2>nul

reg.exe query "HKLM\System\ControlSet002\Services" >> %temp_outpath%\registry_hklm_installed_services_tmp.txt 2>nul

reg.exe query "HKLM\System\ControlSet002\Services" >> registry_hklm_installed_services_tmp.txt 2>nul

for /f "delims=?" %%a in (registry_hklm_installed_services_tmp.txt) do (
set regkey=%%a
call :getvalue
)
goto :parsereg

:getvalue
reg.exe query "!regkey!\Parameters" /v ServiceDll > nul 2>&1 && goto regkeyexist
goto :eof

:regkeyexist
for /f "tokens=2*" %%b in ('reg.exe query "!regkey!\Parameters" /v ServiceDll') do set ImagePath=%%c
call :regag
goto :eof

:regag
echo !ImagePath! >> registry_hklm_installed_services_tmp2.txt
goto :eof

:parsereg
for /f "delims=?" %%a in (registry_hklm_installed_services_tmp2.txt) do echo %%a >> registry_hklm_installed_services_tmp3.txt
```

Comment: Post you code so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `for /f` command to cycle through the lines in the file like you are doing, and pass the line from the file to a subroutine inside the batch file, which will resolve it while it is being passed.  Give the following:

### Test.txt

```
%windir%\test.txt
%programfiles%\Test2.txt
```

This batch file will resolve the environment variables:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%i in (Test.txt) do call :Expand "%%i"

endlocal
goto TheEnd

:Expand
set _var=%1
echo !_var:"=!

:TheEnd
```

This is how the output looks when you run it:

```
c:\>Test.bat
C:\Windows\test.txt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Test2.txt
```

You can redirect the result to a new text file like this:

```
Test.bat > NewFile.txt
```

Or you can modify the original `Test.bat` to output the modified filename under `Expand` instead of echoing it to the console.  It is important to include the quotes around %%i (`"%%i"`) or spaces in the resolved paths will break into multiple variables when calling `Expand` (e.g., %1, %2, %3, etc.).  The `!_var:"=!` removes the quotes.

Comment: So that works great until I get to the following line in the source file: %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\mpsvc.dll.  It parses that as C:\Program Files\Windows and drops "Defender\mpsvc.dll".

Comment: It's just missing the `"delims="` so try it now.

Comment: @foxidrive - Thanks for just tweaking the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will also expand the variables.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (Test.txt) do call echo %%a
pause
```

**Test.txt**

```
%windir%\test.txt
%programfiles%\Test2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q22726616.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('echo %%a') DO (
  ECHO %%b
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22726616.txt` containing your data for my testing.

[fixed following response - `%%b` line]

Comment: So that works great until I get to the following line in the source file: %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\mpsvc.dll. It parses that as C:\Program Files\Windows and drops "Defender\mpsvc.dll".